# Cancelling $timeout doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

Performing the simple task of cancelling a `$timeout` doesn't work. I've got a status box containing messages to the user so if a new message is set before the timeout has run out then I need to restart the timeout by cancelling it and restarting it.

I've looked at the docs and other answers on this site but I don't seem to be doing anything different.

I get no errors. What am I doing wrong?

The service:

```
core.service('statusHandler', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {

    var status = {
        message: '',
        isSuccess: false,
        isActive: false,
        isBoxDirective: false,
        timeout: null
    };

    this.resetStatus = function() {
        status.isSuccess = false;
        status.isActive = false;
        status.isBoxDirective = false;

        $timeout.cancel(status.timeout);
    };

    this.setStatus = function(message, isSuccess, isBoxDirective) {

        status.message = message || 'Something went wrong';
        status.isSuccess = isSuccess;
        status.isActive = true;
        status.isBoxDirective = isBoxDirective;

        status.timeout = $timeout(function() {
            status.isActive = false;
        }, 5000);
    };

    this.getStatus = function() {
        return status;
    };
}]);
```

Then I use it in a directive like this:

```
core.directive('statusBox', ['statusHandler', function(statusHandler) {

    return {
        scope: {},
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'core',
        templateUrl: '/app/views/components/core/status-box.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            scope.$watch(function() {
                return statusHandler.getStatus();
            }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
                ctrl.status = newVal;
            }, true);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Calling the `resetStatus()` from a controller like this:

```
...

var completed;

... some logic to set completed to true ...

$scope.$watch(function() {
    return completed;
}, function(newVal) {

    if (completed) {

        statusHandler.resetStatus();
        statusHandler.setStatus('Videos have finished uploading and are now being processed', true, false);
    }
});

...
```

Comment: Do explain the downvote.

Comment: `scope.$watch` to me isn't being used correctly.

Comment: I think for starters, what are you trying to achieve from a high level

Comment: Do you get any error? Could you paste it?

Comment: @CallumLinington It is when using controller as syntax. Used it everywhere and it works fine. I've got a box that alerts the user with messages, so if a new message is set before the timeout has run out, I need to cancel the timeout and start the timeout again.

Comment: @Raxkin No errors (un)fortunately.

Comment: For what purpose, where are these messages being created?

Comment: @CallumLinington It could be from controllers, directives, you name it. Not really relevant to the question :)

Comment: It's very relevant because it defines how you architect this part of the system. Of which I believe you're doing wrong. You would be better of turning this into a factory following the pub/sub pattern

Comment: Here is an example i created for inter controller/service/factory/directive communication http://plnkr.co/edit/SZl8S2WNpj2kDWiZvmfs?p=preview

Comment: Where are you calling `resetStatus`  ? That's where the timeout cancelling logic is there rt ?

Comment: @Arkantos The reset function is called from a controller when some videos have finished uploading. So at the start it sets a message saying that the videos are uploading, and when they're done it calls resetStatus() first and then sets a new message with setStatus() right after.

Comment: @CallumLinington Having a hard time understanding how that would help me, as I still would require the timeout to be cancelled via a cancel. :o

Comment: The idea is that you just want to send messages to this status directive. These messages can come from anywhere. So in your status directive you use `Communicator.register` which is similar to the `$watch`. In the controllers you would like to send messages from you use the `Communicator.change` to update the new message.

Comment: Can you add that code ? I don't see any issue with the way you define your timeout or the way you cancel it

Comment: @Arkantos Added the code from the controller.

Comment: Not able to make out the exact issue. In your code, you defined `completed` to be a local variable and after updating it, you're defining a new watcher for `completed`. Ideally watcher expressions will be evaluated in a digest cycle. Is there any code that triggers that cycle later in your code ?

Comment: Also I think you should define your watcher first before you update your `completed` variable. In any case, it's hard to identify the issue without looking at entire controller code

Comment: Here is a new [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/zr17Eyh0C2cjczSEIBfu?p=preview) is this not what you're looking for? As you can see the controllers are sending arbitrary messages about something that is being done. A status is being shown.

Comment: @CallumLinington I have only 1 box, and I need this box to disappear and re-appear with a new timer when a message is set while a timeout is active. The setting of the data isn't the issue.

Comment: @CallumLinington It seems to work if I put the $timeout.cancel() function right after the $timeout declaration within the same function. But not from the reset function.

Comment: that is what toastr is demonstrating, but you can just put then you just put the timeout in the directive where it belongs. The timeout is not the services concern if it is being used for view manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve it by just clearing the previous timeout before assigning a new timeout within the same function at the start. Which does the trick!

It appeared to be some sort of function scope issue as calling the function from `resetStatus()` did nothing.

```
this.setStatus = function(message, isSuccess, isBoxDirective) {

    $timeout.cancel(status.timeout);

    status.message = message || 'Something went wrong';
    status.isSuccess = isSuccess;
    status.isActive = true;
    status.isBoxDirective = isBoxDirective;

    status.timeout = $timeout(function() {
        status.isActive = false;
    }, 5000);
};
```

Comment: This fixed my issue as well. Though i never initiate the timeout anywhere else, for some reason, I have to cancel it before setting it!